# Replacing digits in C# string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am trying to use regular expressions to do some work on strings but I am having some difficulty. My goal is to replace numbers in a string with a character, specifically if there is a group of numbers in the string I want to replace the entire group of numbers with a `*`. If there is just a single digit I want to replace that with a `?`.

For example, if I had the string "test12345.txt" I would like to turn that to "test*.txt", but if I have "test1.txt" I would like to turn that to just "test?.txt".

I tried

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+", RegexOptions.None);
returnString = r.Replace(returnString, "*");
```

But this replaces replaces even a single digit on its own with a `*`

Comment: Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+", RegexOptions.None);
returnString = r.Replace(returnString, "*"); But this replaces replaces even a single digit on its own with a \*

Comment: @Jim, you have to use two regexes for your problem, see below

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is pretty easy with [Regex.Replace](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace)

```
string input = "test12345.txt";

// replace all numbers with a single *
string replacedstar = Regex.Replace( input, "[0-9]{2,}", "*" );

// replace remaining single digits with ?
string replacedqm = Regex.Replace( input, "[0-9]", "?" );
```

Comment: Is there a way to replace this all numbers with * at each position ?
eg. input:  test1234
results in: test****

Thanks in advance

Comment: `[0-9]` does not cover other languages, `\d` is recommended for global contexts since it checks for other languages' digits too

Answer (score 4):

This will do, first it will match more than two digits and replace the complete block with `*` and the 2nd statement is for if there's single digit, it will replace with `?`'

```
var newFileName = Regex.Replace(fileName, @"\d{2,}", "*");
newFileName = Regex.Replace(fileName, @"\d", "?");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Do this with two regexes:

- replace `\d{2,}` with `*`,
- replace `\d` with `?`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    static string ReplaceNumbers(string text)
    {
        string output = Regex.Replace(text, @"\d{2,}", "*");
        output = Regex.Replace(output, @"\d", "?");
        return output;
    }
```

- \d is for digit
- {2,} means at least 2 digits with no max limit

Comment: Does `\d{1,1}` ensure that there is only one digit? Or would it still match "2" from the string "23"? If not, what's the difference between `\d{1,1}` and just `\d` ?

Comment: @jb there is no difference between \d{1,1} and \d

Answer (score 0):

```
        int n1 = Convert.ToInt32(number.Text);
        int n2 = Convert.ToInt32(replace.Text);
        int n3 = Convert.ToInt32(othernumber.Text);
        int temp;
        int result = 0;
        int i = 1;
        while (n1 > 0)
        {
            temp = n1 % 10;
            if (n2 == temp)
            {
                result += n3 * i;
            }
            else
            {
                result = result + temp * i;
            }
            i *= 10;
            n1 = n1 / 10;
        }
        afterswap.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
```