# Replace RX123456789 with RX********* using REGEX

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using C# to create a pattern in order to replace all the occurrences in a string from

```
RX123456789 into RX*********
```

I have tried various patterns without success. I'm kinda new regarding Regular Expression.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please show what patterns you *have* tried - and any other constraints. For example, are you happy just to replace *all* digits in the string with *, or do you need to make sure they're only after "RX"?

Comment: Is the count of '*' always fixed?

Comment: Is the requirement just to replace all numbers in a string with a *? Or is the RX123456789 going to appear as part of a larger string which may have other numbers and you just need to match numbers starting RX? Also is the length of the string of numbers fixed or variable?

Comment: Yes, I want to make sure they are after RX

Comment: show some of the patterns you have tried. And show some more context of the string, ie, wheter each of this expressions is in a separate line, separators, ... I suppose the number of * should match the number of digits replaced?

Comment: You only have numbers after RX? you want to replace everything after RX until you have a whispace? You should put a full string of a possible input you may have and then show us the expected output. And remember, when trying regex: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Try regex `^RX\S*$`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31006413/3832970) will give you a hint on what regex you can use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586954/replacing-digits-in-c-sharp-string this answer will also help

Comment: please check my answer @redviper2100

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex:-

```
string data = "RX123456789";


var resultString = Regex.Replace(data, @"[0-9]", "*");
```

If you need * of number only When **RX** is present then use this logic:-

```
string data = "RX123456789";
var resultString="";
if (new Regex("RX([0-9]+)").IsMatch(data))
{
    resultString = Regex.Replace(data, @"[0-9]", "*");
}
```

Comment: If there are other numbers (not prefixed with "RX") AND the requirement is to only replace the prefixed numbers, this will fail (it replaces *any* digit). Granted, the requirements are not entirely clear

Comment: if they need only the number to replace with the star where RX is present then they need to use this kind of regex (RX[0-9]+) @HansKeﬆing

Comment: @D-johnAnshani: You fixed the search part, but not the replace part. Consider a string like `RX1234 some text 5678` this will end up as `RX**** some text ****` which does not seem to meet redviper's requirements